# How to delete unused IDC_* entries from AppResourceId.h

Tags: tizen

When I rename IDs of controls in Native UI Builder, old names are left unused. Is there any convenient way to eliminate these cluttered unused constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the names from the `AppResourceId.h` and also from `AppResourceId.cpp`if there's the definition of the same, It wont do any harm.

Comment: Thank you, yes, so at least for now I have to manually delete them? It seems a little bit counterintuitive that the GUI for renaming does not complete its job...

Comment: Sometimes GUI tool doesn't create the id itself ,So we need to create the id ourselves, Hoping these will be addressed soon